# Are our prints being recorded or monitored in an office printer?

Tags: networking, printing, printer, wired-networking

I was reading a joke about someone doing a prank via the office printer.
In the end they found him via the printer queue.
I was curious do companies record all documents we send to the printer?
So if we print something personal could this be read by someone else as well?

(http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2732898/Dear-Sandwich-Thief-Mans-hilarious-response-passive-aggressive-sign-posted-offices-fridge-door-sparks-incredible-kitchen-note-war.html)

Comment: They can be depends how it's configured

Answer (score 7):

Possibly yes, it would depend on the printer software or whether the IT people installed additional software to save every printout. Some companies have programs to monitor their workers in various ways. You would never know, but you could try asking your IT department.

In addition there might be some monitoring function built into the printer itself. For example many laser printers mark each document with almost invisible yellow dots. These can identify the printer and time of printing.

Comment: https://www.eff.org/issues/printers

Comment: I worked at a company that did *a lot* of printing.  Manuals, documents, etc.  We had millions of dollars worth of high end printers, the cost of paper and toner was exorbitant.  As the sys admin in charge of printers, they asked me to make sure this money was not being wasted.  We did monitor what was being printed and found many employees were printing out a lot of personal files.

Comment: Would the IT admit that?

Answer (score 4):

Even if it isn't intended, many high end printers have a hard drive where the documents are stored before they are rendered (printed).  There have been many reports of documents being retrieved from second hand printers.

Paranoid yet?

Comment: While this was true and may still be in some cases, most printer companies encrypt the drives now.

Answer (score 1):

In your case specifically we can't give an answer. You'd have to ask HR and IT for that information.

As a general rule of thumb it's best to assume that everything you do on company equipment, or on the company network, is monitored or logged - with the possible exception of things like passwords (though this isn't always true either).

If HR has a privacy policy or equipment usage policy somewhere, give it a read.

Comment: Would IT or HR admit that?

Comment: That's another question that can't be given a decisive answer. They don't legally have to tell you what they monitor, at the federal level. It varies state to state. You have no legal expectation of privacy while using company equipment (including the network), or while on company premises. However, if they do say "yes we monitor x y and z", you can logically be assured that they do. That doesn't mean that they don't monitor more than that, and a "no" doesn't necessarily mean no. To answer your specific question, monitoring print jobs is not out of the ordinary.